# How to think of a Courant algebroid?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am trying to read read the paper [Courant Algebroids and Strongly Homotopy Lie Algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802118v1) by Dmitry Roytenberg, Alan Weinstein.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. A Courant algebroid on $M$ is a vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ with the folllowing extra data:

1. There is a binary operation (skew-symmetric) $[-,-]:\Gamma(M,E)\times \Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ (just like the case of Lie algebroid, but, it need not satisfy the Jacobi identity).
2. There is a bilinear form $\left<-,-\right>:\Gamma(M,E)\times \Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ non-degenerate, symmmetric) this is somewhat new for me, I know the notion of "metric on vector bundles", but did not use it yet).
3. There is a map $\mathcal{D}:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$. It would be slightly less surprising if the map $\mathcal{D}$ is from $C^\infty(M)$ to $\Gamma(M,E^*)$. This is because, there is one obvious  way to assign an element of $\Gamma(M,E^*)$ for an element in $C^\infty(M)$, namely $f\mapsto df\mapsto \pi^* (df)$ for $f\in C^\infty(M)$. It is mentioned that, the ''bilinear form'' gives an isomorphism $\Gamma(M,E^*)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$, and the map $\mathcal{D}$ is just the composition $C^\infty(M)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E^*)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ (upto a small correction by a constant). This map $\mathcal{D}$ is completely  determined by the bilinear form $\left<-,-\right>$. So, this is not actually a separate data. It is coming from the second data mentioned above.

These three data are asked to satisfy some conditions. In total, there are $5$ conditions, out of which $2$ are expected, $1$ is fair enough, the other $2$ are surprising and unmotivated (in first few readings).

1. It is already mentioned that $[-,-]:\Gamma(M,E)\times \Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ does not satisfy the Jacobi condition. It would be useful to know how bad the situation is (how much the Jacobi condition is deviated). The first condition says the situation is not bad, and the Jacobi condition is controlled in a nice way with the help of the map $\mathcal{D}:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$. We have
   $$[[\alpha_1,\alpha_2],\alpha_3]+[[\alpha_2,\alpha_3],\alpha_1]+[[\alpha_3,\alpha_1],\alpha_2]=\mathcal{D}(T(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)),$$
   where $T(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)\in C^\infty(M)$ is a nice function produced from $[-,-]$ and $\left<-,-\right>$.
2. In case of Lie algebroid, we have said the morphism $\rho^\#:\Gamma(M,A)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,TM)$ is a morphism of Lie bracket. In case of Courant algebroids, we can't ask the map $\rho^\#:\Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,TM)$ to be Lie bracket preserving, but, we can ask that the map $\rho^\#:\Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,TM)$ preserves the binary operations on $\Gamma(M,E)$ and $\Gamma(M,TM)$, namely
   $$\rho^\# ([\alpha_1,\alpha_2])=[\rho^\#\alpha_1,\rho^\#\alpha_2],$$
   for all $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in \Gamma(M,E)$.
3. In case of Lie algebroid, we ask that the action of $C^\infty(M)$ on $\Gamma(M,A)$ is compatible with the Lie bracket operation on $\Gamma(M,A)$; that is, we have
   $$[\alpha, f\alpha_2]=f[\alpha_1,\alpha_2]+(\rho(\alpha_1) f)\alpha_2,$$
   for all $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in \Gamma(M,A)$. In case of Courant algebroid, we ask the same thing, with a slight correction term that comes from the maps $\left<-,-\right>$ and $\mathcal{D}$. We have,
   $$[\alpha, f\alpha_2]=f[\alpha_1,\alpha_2]+(\rho(\alpha_1) f)\alpha_2 
   \color{red}{-\left<\alpha_1,\alpha_2\right>\mathcal{D}(f)},$$
   for all $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in \Gamma(M,E)$ and $f\in C^\infty(M)$.
4. some strange condition that says $\left<\mathcal{D}(f),\mathcal{D}(g)\right>=0$ for all $f,g\in C^\infty(M)$.
5. another strange condition that says
   $$\rho(\alpha)\left<\beta_1,\beta_2\right>
   =\left<[\alpha,\beta_1]+\mathcal{D}\left<\alpha,\beta_1\right>,\beta_2\right>+
   \left<\beta_1,[\alpha,\beta_2]+\mathcal{D}\left<\alpha,\beta_2\right>\right>$$
   for all $\alpha,\beta_1,\beta_2\in \Gamma(M,E)$. There is a slight symmetry between first part and second part of the right side. Suppose we take three elements of $\Gamma(M,A)$, two of them combine to give an element in $C^\infty(M)$, one of them gives an element in $\Gamma(M,TM)=\mathfrak{X}(M)$. One can apply the vector field $\rho(\alpha)\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ on smooth map $\left<\beta_1,\beta_2\right>\in C^\infty(M)$ to get an element $\rho(\alpha)\left<\beta_1,\beta_2\right>\in C^\infty(M)$. One way to get an element in $C^\infty(M)$ from elements of $\Gamma(M,E)$ is by tactically applying $\left<-,-\right>$. I think that is what is done in this case.

I am having difficulty in understanding the conditions 4 and 5. Any extra insight will be helpful. Please let me know any freely available materials that discuss these conditions of Courant algebroids in detail.

Comment: It's not clear to me what sort of understanding of the definition you're looking for. Have you done the exercise of verifying that the axioms hold in the key examples? [According to the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Courant%20algebroid), there are several equivalent ways to define a Courant algebroid -- have you looked at some of these other definitions to see if they make more sense to you? What are you trying to get out of this paper? Why are you interested in Courant algebroids?

Comment: I'm afraid this is one of the cases when to understand what's going on you have to make it far worse than it is. Namely, look into "[The first Pontryagin class](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/first-pontryagin-class/1AAD5769F9E5F619C87FDFB831D2CF5D)" by Paul Bressler (Compositio **143** (2007) 1127-1163) where Courant algebroids are understood as quasiclassical limits of vertex algebroids. The latter have been treated in many subsequent papers; I would recommend the Gálvez - Gorbounov - Tonks paper, for example

Comment: @TimCampion what equivalent ways of Courant algebroids are you referring in n lab page? The equivalent ways mentioned in the section 1) as Idea? Please tell me if you really think they are readable :D

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Oh :D So, you think I am trying to make an easy thing look so complicated... ? Or, you mean in that paper they have made it complicated? :D I will see that paper as well...

Comment: I just mean there have been further developments. Certainly I find Bressler's version somehow better connected to several other things. Which are not so easy themselves, but...

Comment: Maybe this could be useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00265

Comment: Name of @unknownymous's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417079/how-to-think-of-a-courant-algebroid#comment1070390_417079):  [Letters to Alan Weinstein about Courant algebroids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00265).

Comment: There is no condition in the definition that requires $\langle{-}, {-}\rangle$ to be non-degenerate?  Otherwise I do not see how you get any sort of isomorphism $\Gamma(M, E^*) \to \Gamma(M, E)$.

Comment: @LSpice yes, non-degenerate.. typo :) I was trying to make the definition look nice by writing **binary operation** in 1st condition, **bilinear form** in 2nd condition.. I thought of writing that it is non-degenerate but forgot to add it :D

Comment: @unknownymous many thanks.. that is interesting...

Comment: @unknownymous Though it is interesting and useful, there seem to be some different point of view.. a choice of skewsymmetric bracket and non-skewsymmetric bracket.. One thing that makes me feel comfortable is that, the point 4 I mentioned as strange to me is also "mysterious" to Pavol Severa (if I understand correctly).. it would be useful if you can give some rough explanation of what it said (concerned with the definition)... I will anyways read it :)